# Using akka actor in Play Framework 2.5

Tags: playframework, code-injection

I am trying to understand how to use Actors in Play Framework 2.5.
I basically added the example for the website, but am having problems with my constructor. I am sure it is a basic mistake by not specifying something correctly, but I can't see it.My feeling it is with the public StreamingControl(ActorSystem system), but that is what is in the example.

In my build.sbt:

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

My routes:

```
GET     /streaming/controlRoom/:id       controllers.StreamingControl.controlRoom(id: Long)
POST    /streaming/controlRoom/:id/changeScene controllers.StreamingControl.changeScene(id: Long)
```

Then my controller class:

```
package controllers;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import exceptions.StreamingException;
import logic.Logger;
import models.StreamingEvent;
import models.UserTask;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters;
import streamingControl.StreamingEventControlActor;
import streamingControl.StreamingEventControlProtocol;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import static akka.pattern.Patterns.ask;

@Singleton
@Check(UserTask.BASIC)
public class StreamingControl extends Controller {

    final ActorRef controllerRef;

    @Inject
    public StreamingControl(ActorSystem system) {
        controllerRef = system.actorOf(StreamingEventControlActor.props);
    }

    @Check(UserTask.BASIC)
    public Result controlRoom(Long id){
        StreamingEvent item = StreamingEvent.findById(id);
        if(item == null) return notFound();

        return ok(views.html.streaming.controlRoomView.render(item));
    }

    @Check(UserTask.BASIC)
    public Result changeScene(Long id) {
        StreamingEvent item = StreamingEvent.findById(id);
        try {
            return FutureConverters.toJava(ask(controllerRef, new StreamingEventControlProtocol.StreamingEventControl("test"), 1000))
                            .thenApply(response -> ok((String) response)).toCompletableFuture().get();
        } catch (StreamingException e) {
            Logger.warn("Problem: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            return ok("Problem: " + e.getMessage() + " (" + e.getStatus() + ")");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn("Problem: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            return ok("Problem: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

The error is:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at controllers.StreamingControl.<init>(StreamingControl.java:27)
  at controllers.StreamingControl.class(StreamingControl.java:27)
  while locating controllers.StreamingControl
    for parameter 8 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:92)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at controllers.StreamingControl.<init>(StreamingControl.java:27)
  at controllers.StreamingControl.class(StreamingControl.java:27)
  while locating controllers.StreamingControl
    for parameter 8 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:92)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:158)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem, it was somewhere in the StreamingEventControlActor class. I don't know what exactly, but deleted it all and rewrite it and it worked.